# Angular PWA in Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, azure-static-web-app

Does anyone have experience hosting Angular PWA apps in new Azure resource, [Static Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/static/)?

I tried to modified `routes.json` file:

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/*",
            "serve": "/index.html",
            "statusCode": 200
        }
    ],
    "mimeTypes": {
        "json": "application/json",
        "webmanifest": "application/json"
    }
}
```

but without success.

[image]

When I deploy the same app to Azure Web App with `web.config`

```xml
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension="webmanifest" mimeType="application/json" />  
  <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />           
</staticContent>
```

PWA is installable.

[Demo project is there.](https://github.com/Burgyn/Sample.AngularOnAzureStaticWebApps)

Thanks.

Comment: change the mimeType for your manifest to 

application/manifest+json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we configure any app to Azure static Web app it uses `npm run build` as default command for building an application. Now in the case of Angular application, it uses the same command which internally runs `ng build`. But the issue here is that its not run in prod mode. So we can configure the custom build command by adding `app_build_command` in workflow file and use `npm run build -- --prod` as its value.

`app_build_command: "npm run build -- --prod"`

Here are some useful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/front-end-frameworks
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/github-actions-workflow#custom-build-commands

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
I tried to add a variable name in pipeline variable $deployment_token which is the deployment token in Azure static web app in Azure portal.
Then I created a pipeline to use the angular code like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
      app_location: "/" 
      Routes Location:"add the address of routes.json"
      app_build_command: "npm install -g @angular/cli&& npm install && ng build --prod"
       output_location: "dist"
   env:
       azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```